# Fingerstyle guitar - limited pinky finger reach

Tags: guitar, technique, fingerstyle-guitar

I'm struggling to play this phrase. I can reach only 4th fret using pinky finger. Although I can and play this shape two frets above. How should I approach learning in order to eventually be able to play it? Or is there some other fingering possible?

```
E|--5-----------
B|--2-----------
G|--3-----3-----
D|-----2-----2--
A|--3-----------
E|--------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a capo on the third fret. Call this the open string. If this becomes too easy to play with the stretch, move the capo down a fret.Continue until you can play it in the correct place. You don't give any clues as to whether you are young, with small hands, or what. The answer may be to wait till your hands grow,or change to a smaller scale guitar.

Comment: This phrase has notes on the second fret, so a capo on the third would require re-voicing.

Comment: The  whole phrase will of course be in a different key with my suggestion.The object is to get used to the feel of the fingering, but with a smaller stretch.

Comment: Oh! I understand now. For some reason I thought you meant something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

Nice chord! Tim's advice is great here. Just one other thing you could try: assuming you are playing this passage with a first finger barre on fret 2 (which you *should* be, in order to have the fret 2 notes on strings 2 and 4 sound together), push your first finger further up than it needs to go, all the way up to about string 6. I find this makes it easier for me to extend my little finger (pinky) to fret 5.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issues with limited pinky reach.

How I overcame this was by doing **a lot** of various exercises involving finger stretches and larger/difficult chords.

At the end of the day it just became easier the more I practiced it.